# Update toolbar notification count by calling backgound method continuously windows

Tags: c#

how can i call method continuously to update toolbar notification which showing pending notification count in the main Window in my Windows application 
i want to write common class for that but am not able to call toolbarbutton in my class method.

button dont have any event am just updating button text only and if create method in mainwindow how can i call method from class . i can call like this new formmain().updatetext(); but it will initialize form again i dont want to do that

Comment: i dont know why people are down voting instead of giving answear.if it is not useful give me the useful one

Comment: I should be able to pass the `toolbarbutton` to you class from `Main Window` but the button event must be on `Main Window`.

Comment: button dont have any event am just updating button text only and if create method in mainwindow how can i call method from class . i can call like this new formmain().updatetext(); but it will initialize form again i dont want to do that

Comment: You can pass the current mainwindow istance to your class and save it in a property, then you can call updatetext in this way: `yourpropertythatcontainsmainwindowistance.updatetext();`

Comment: could you plz give me simple example

Comment: thank its working how can i mark as answeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class:

```
public class OtherClass {
    public static MainWindow mw { get; set; }

    // any other things

    public static void MethodThatCallUpdateText(){
        mw.updatetext();
    }
}
```

In your MainWindow:

```
OtherClass.mw = this;
```

And where you want:

```
OtherClass.MethodThatCallUpdateText();
```